# Place div infront of input element in Zend form

Tags: php, css, zend-framework2, zend-form

Im working on zend form..My problem is..
I have designed sigin and sign up froms using zend forms.My sample snippet is..

```
$this->addElement('Text', 'email', array(
  'label' => $email,
  'required' => true,
  'allowEmpty' => false,

  'inputType' => 'email',

  'placeholder' => 'Hello@gmail.com',

));

<div id="email-element" class="form-element">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=""  autofocus="autofocus"     placeholder="Hello@gmail.com"></div>
```

But I need to place a div with name email_icon with class name form_icon infront of input element to place an image..But Im unable to get snippets to place div in zend form elements.Could you please help me for few snippets..o tuts..or some guidance..

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the email input element in your view script, as per Zend Framework 2, you can use below code snippet.

```
echo "<div id='email_icon_div'>";
echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'));
echo "</div><div class='clr'></div>";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this was not placing inside the parent div

Comment: I hope, you want to display email icon, right? If so, position email icon with your CSS.